# How to calculate hours/month usage on Amazon RDS and Pricing?

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I never used Amazon EC2 or RDS Service. I am trying to calculate my cost using http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

I searched a little but could locate answers to some basic things. Can you help me out with this:

1. What does DB Instance means? 1 Database = 1 Instance or 1 Connection = 1 Instance
2. How to calculate hours/month usage? It should depend on the transfer rates or processing time. Is there a way I can get rough Idea about it?
3. What if I already have my DB Ready and want to upload it directly (it would be few GBs) then how will it be calculated.

I am new to amazon EC2 and searched stackoverflow and serverfault before posting this question. Got some idea but not specific what I am looking for. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In general, one database = one instance. You spin up instances, and do what you like with them. Definitely possible to have more connections to it.
2. Hours per month is just that. How many hours per month you have the instance active. If you plan to have the instance active 24/7, you may find more cost effective alternatives with other cloud providers. If you run it less often than that, you save money when it's not active. It's billed hourly to your account at the rate specified.
3. Upload data is counted at the standard transfer rates. A few GBs doesn't cost much, but you will be paying for the service starting the moment you spin up the instance.

Comment: Hmmm. Thats pretty good then. That means if I use database for only 2 hours/day only and perform all the operation in that time (no matter how processor intensive they are) I will be charged only for that period (2 hours). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, welcome to clouds :). Although, you will still be charged a trivial amount more for your EBS usage for the month, but the instance cost is likely to be higher. Another option is to ask for a spot instance (you bid for unused capacity). You should be able to get a spot instance at half the cost of a normal instance. When you're finished with it, snapshot it and use that snapshot next time.

Comment: Thanks @David. I can't believe its calculating to only $8 a month. pretty cheap. :)

Comment: Yep. Cloud computing can be really cheap. Just remember that you'll actually have to build the infrastructure to spin it up and down when you need it, which can be something of a pain. And as David said, use the spot pricing to get better rates if your task doesn't have a very specific timeframe.

Comment: We have a site in which database pages are not public yet, but we have a Quartz job that runs so often, and it uses 600 hrs a month.  If you are planning a budget, I would plan for 100% usage or 800 hrs a month.